# How to take a screenshot from Azure Devops macos agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm running some UI tests on Azure DevOps and my UI tests, which runs smoothly on Linux agents, are getting stuck on macOS (I have tested the code on a mac mini, it works perfectly).

I now that my tests start the execution, because I had executed some "Hello World" code without issues, but when it comes to my code, it basically hangs.

How I can debug Azure DevOps agents? If I got a screenshot, would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using sprunge:

```
uuencode foo.jpg < ost.jpg | | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us

output: http://sprunge.us/<hash>
```